# Congruence among different values within samples

Tags: r, statistics

I'd like to test the congruence among different scores within each sampled site. These scores were calculated with five different methods to measure species diversity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index). For instance, if the value of index "a" is high, should the value of index b, c, d, and e by high as well? In this way, I'd like to calculate that congruence within each sampled site.

Should you guys suggest any method to test this congruence? I've tried to calculate the coefficient of variation within each site, but it does not make sense to me because they vary in different scales. I provided an example of the dataset below.

Thank you in advance.

#### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(11, 5, 2), 
                 b=rnorm(11, 1, 1), 
                 c=rnorm(11, 2, 1), 
                 d=rnorm(11, 0, 1), 
                 e=rnorm(11, 3, 2))
rownames(df) <- paste("site", 1:11, sep="")
df
```

Comment: I believe this could be a legitimate use case for principle component analysis. Looking at `summary(prcomp(df, scale.=TRUE))` we see that each principle component explains more than 10 % of the variance, so there isn't much congruence, as can be expected from your artificial data (I used `set.seed(42)` prior to random number generation).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I liked of your suggestion. However, I was just wondering how can I decide between "congruence" and "incongruence", since I need to decide between them. For instance, I used PCA in my data and found that PC1 and PC2 explained respectively 44% and 28% of the variation.

Comment: ... Do you have any suggestion @Roland? Maybe a random expectation should be 20% (5 / 100) for each PC, but I don't know how I can test it. Thank you. –

Answer (score 0):

A classification tree would automatically optimize your congruence index. The `rpart` package in R offers the Gini index and the Information index (I think that is the same as the Entropy Index). You would need to stack your data (using `reshape2` package here). In this example I assumed you were trying to classify `species` by the numeric observation and the site location.

Also if you have a more statistics inspired question with a bit of R, you should feel free to try https://stats.stackexchange.com/

```
require(rpart)
require(reshape2)
df$site = rownames(df)
stackDF = melt(df, variable.name="species", value.name="observation")
str(stackDF)
classTree <- rpart(species ~ observation + site,data=stackDF, parms=list(split="gini"))
# classTree <- rpart(species ~ site + observation,data=stackDF, parms=list(split="information"))
printcp(classTree)
table(actual=stackDF$species, predicted=predict(classTree,type="class"))
plot(classTree,compress=T,uniform=T,branch=0.4,margin=0.1)
text(classTree)
```

Roland makes a good suggestion to use principal components. You can use `pck = princomp(stackDF[,-which(colnames(stackDF)=="species"),drop=F])` and then change the formula in your tree to be `stackDF$species ~ pck +...`. You can check the cross-validation with `printcp` and prune the tree with `prune`.

```
> table(actual=stackDF$species, predicted=predict(classTree,type="class"))
      predicted
actual  a  b  c  d  e
     a 10  1  0  0  0
     b  0  6  3  2  0
     c  0  1  9  1  0
     d  0  3  0  8  0
     e  9  0  0  2  0
```

Of course none of the classifications in the example make sense because they are random.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HansRoggeman. I'll study rpart to understand your suggestion. Just a correction, my column represents different species diversity indices. Thus, each observation is a value of a diversity index at each locality. As I have five different indices I'm trying to test their congruence within localities. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are just looking for optimization of the index, create different functions for the index and use the `optim` function. But you will be throwing away all the information you have from other factors. if you want to use that information you should use classification trees (like the ones in `rpart`) or another prediction technique (like multinomial logit - not using these information indices) but I am sure there other CART packages out there.